# How did the cross-linguistic univerbation 'nothing/not/none/no + less' semantically shift to signify 'despite'?

Tags: etymology, latin

Several European languages have (false?) cognate adverbs with the meaning of  ['nevertheless'](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/nevertheless) (and 'nonetheless') built from words meaning "nothing/not/none/no" and "less".

> despite something that you have just mentioned

What semantic notions underlie their original ("nothing/never the less") and contemporary (similar to that of English 'nevertheless' above)?

French has ['néanmoins'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%C3%A9anmoins) and had (now obsolete) [neantmoins](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neantmoins#French).

> Etymology: [néant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%C3%A9ant#French) (“nothing”) +‎ *[moins](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moins#French)* (“less”)

Italian has ['nondimeno'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nondimeno#Italian)

> From *[non](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non#Italian)* +‎ *[di](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/di#Italian)* +‎ *[meno](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meno#Italian)*.

Dutch's [*niettemin*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/niettemin#Dutch) and German's ['nichtsdestoweniger'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nichtsdestoweniger#German) are calques from  Latin.

> From *[niet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/niet#Dutch)* (“not”) +‎ *[te](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/te#Dutch)* (“too”) +‎ *[min](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/min#Dutch)* (“insignificant, less(er), small(er)”), [calque](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#calque) of [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[nihilōminus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nihilominus#Latin)*.
>
> Loan translation of [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[nihilōminus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nihilominus#Latin)*.

Comment: Please post your English etymology questions at [english.se].

Comment: The trouble is that it's such an obvious and tiny shift that you will never be able to tell where it has been calqued from another language and where it has arisen in parallel.

Comment: You've now turned an acceptable question into an off-topic one. Arbitrary meaning changes are not good questions for this site.

Comment: @curiousdannii "Arbitrary meaning changes" : How do you know this is arbitrary?

Comment: There is a potentially interesting question about the origins of words like nevertheless (and whether they are calques, independent developments, or stem from a common ancestor). However, it is unclear to me what the quote "despite something that you have just mentioned" has to do with it. "Nevertheless" and "despite" are not interchangeable (so I also don't understand the title).

Comment: @Keelan I quoted 'despite something that you have just mentioned' to tender the definition of 'nevertheless'.

Comment: That seems more an issue of pragmatics, then, am I right? I would clarify that. As it stands, the title of the question still suggests to me that you think that "nevertheless" and "despite" mean the same, and the quote in the body of the question is not introduced.

Comment: @Keelan Isn't this etymology or historical linguistics?

Comment: Yes, but you're asking about the pragmatics of nevertheless (from a historical perspective), more so than its semantics, right?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. While it may not be considered a good question for this site (as shown by the downvotes), it doesn't seem to be about language-specific grammar and usage—it's asking if there's an underlying reason for the same shift happening in several different languages, which can be answered within the scope of this site.

Comment: @curiousdannii See https://youtu.be/iLKDYqxWY7w?t=97.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest looking at "nonetheless" rather than "nevertheless": "never" in this case is being used as an intense negative (it's a somewhat archaic/regional thing nowadays, but survives in "well I never!") instead of as "not ever". Something something Jespersen's cycle.

That said, the oldest attested construction like this seems to be Latin *nihilō minus*: literally "less" (*minus*) + "by nothing" (*nihilō*). The original meaning is something like "not decreased/lessened at all".

This literal meaning is found in Cicero (*Pro Milone* 19), for example:

> *minus dolendum fuit rē non perfectā, sed puniendum certe nihilō minus*
>   There should certainly be less grieving, since the action wasn't actually completed—but it deserves to be punished **not any less [severely]**.

In other words, the punishment should not be lesser, just because the crime wasn't actually committed.

It's only a small leap from this to the modern idiom:

> But [an incomplete crime] deserves to be punished **nonetheless**.

Since the English, French, and so on all line up so well with the Latin, I postulate that they're all calques from the Latin. The written record doesn't give much evidence one way or another, but the fact that they all follow the Latin word order is telling.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote.